# Gmail False positive spam even when people reply to me

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention

Sometimes Gmail marks as spam an email I receive that is a reply to something I wrote. The reason it presents is `Lots of messages from mydomain.com were identified as spam in the past`. My emails are sent via my domain host, and are received back also through it, forwarded to my gmail account, this way:

```
Sender -> myemail@myhost.com -> mygmail@gmail.com
```

Some months ago I asked my host about this and they said they added SPF and DKIM, but it's still happening.

My domain is not blacklisted on any site I looked in (spamhaus.org, senderbase.org, email-checker.com, mxtoolbox.com). On mail-tester.com it claims my message is not signed with DKIM, but that is for a message I'm sending.

What should I do? Can I contact Google about this? Haven't found any way of doing it.

Here's the full email header: https://pastebin.com/AvfeaStQ

Here's how it look on Gmail:

[image]

Comment: Are you on dedicated hosting? If you are on a shared account, it is possible that it is not your domain that is declared as spam but another one sharing the same IP address.

Comment: This is an old question, but I've suddenly seen a spike in Gmail "spam" false positives recently. Across several accounts, not just mine. From personal emails to shopping orders. Gmail used to be great for spam detection, but I'm having to check the spam folder several times a day which kinda defeats the point. And I can't see that it is learning from "Report not spam" as it's repeatedly filtering the same type of email (even from the same people/sites) as spam.

Comment: I actually got a [response from @gmail on Twitter](https://twitter.com/gmail/status/1519740195557543940): "Our team is working on this issue. ... Thanks for your patience."